# How can I return 404 when a user tries to manually browse to any ".php" extension on my site?

Tags: nginx

I use PHP.  I like to hide that I do.  I used to have all of my PHP inside `.html` files, but frankly it's annoying having to reconfigure every editor/tool I use that `.html` actually means a PHP file.

So I've moved them all to .php, like a grown-up.

The extensions are hidden via `try_files` anyway - I didn't know about that when I was first setting out.

But a user can guess `www.domain.com/index.php`, and given that it loads fine, they'll know the site is built using PHP.

A minor issue, but one I'd like to quash.  But how?

I naively tried this, near the top of my `server` block:

```
location ~ (\.php$) {
    return 404;
}
```

But that 404'd everything on the site.  I guess because the location matches on the actual script that gets run, as opposed to what's in the user's address bar?

I then commented out the 404 line which had the LOVELY (/s) effect of sending my backend code to visitors as a download, along with their 404 page.  I think because you can only match one location block, so it was matching, but then doing nothing with it, and just serving the code up?

Eurgh.

Before that I had tried

```
if( $request_uri ~ '\.php$' ) { return 404 ; }
```

In my `server` block.  But that didn't seem to have any effect.

Given the disaster I created, I've decided to ask the experts...

Thank you!

Comment: I see now my error was just in not having a space between `if` and `(`.  Added a space and `reload`ed nginx and it works as expected 

Answer (score 1):

Don't. There's a few ways to solve this:

1. Give up. Let people do what you want to avoid. The downside is negligible; any attacker worth their salt won't be defeated by what you do.
2. Use a [URL rewrite to rewrite URLs](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) so what people see in the browser doesn't correspond to the filename. Keep your files as `foo.php`, but rewrite URL to `example.com/foo.html`.

For #2, something like

```
rewrite ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php last;
```

should probably work.

Comment: I agree with point 1, largely.  But if I DID want to do it... I don't think your point 2 answers what I was asking.  That wouldn't stop someone going to `example.com/foo.php` and seeing that that file appears to exist.

Comment: @Codemonkey rewrite `^.*php$` to 404.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I knew you could use `rewrite` like that.  Is that better than `if ($request_uri ~ '\.php$') { return 404; }`, and if so why?  Thank you  (See comment on my question)

Comment: And why did you change it from `^(.*)\.html$` to `^.*php$`?  (Other than - obviously - the `html`/`php` change!)

Comment: I don't know Nginx, so you would have to look up the particulars. If `if` is better? Maybe, I don't know.

Comment: `if` is a tricky concept that has confusing side effects: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: @Codemonkey the syntax is regexp. That's worthy of a book and a box of aspirin, but in short `(.*)` matches any number of any character and saves it for reuse, so we can use it as `$1` later. `^` matches start of line, `$` end of line. `.` is any character, and `*` is zero or more of preceeding character.

Comment: Yep, I'm fine with regexps - nginx is an unintuitive beast though, and I wondered if there was good reason why you changed it between your answer and your follow-up comment.  I realise now it's just because you didn't need the capturing group for the 404 rewrite 